# Can't write on a CFWriteStream successfully created with CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket

Tags: ios, sockets, stream, ios-simulator

I am facing a problem when I try to establish a bidirectional asynchronous communication thanks to CFWrite/ReadStream in the iOS development framework.

I start to create a socket connection, and all seems to be right :

```
CFSocketContext socketCtx = {0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL};
socket = CFSocketCreate(NULL, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP,kCFSocketConnectCallBack, (CFSocketCallBack)onConnectOrDisconnect, &socketCtx);

CFSocketEnableCallBacks(socket, kCFSocketConnectCallBack);
struct sockaddr_in addr;
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_len = sizeof(addr);
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(appDelegate.portSocket);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr([adress cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
CFDataRef connectAddr = CFDataCreate(NULL, (unsigned char *)&addr, sizeof(addr));   
CFRunLoopSourceRef sourceRef = CFSocketCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, socket, 0);
CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), sourceRef, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
CFRelease(sourceRef);
CFSocketConnectToAddress(socket, connectAddr, -1);
```

Then, in my connection callback, I create two streams, one for reading, the other for writing :

```
void onConnectOrDisconnect(CFSocketRef socket, CFSocketCallBackType type, CFDataRef address,
                           const void *data, void *info)
{
    TCPClient * clientTCP = (TCPClient *)info;
    if(data==NULL)
    {
        [clientTCP ConnectionSuccess];
    }else {
        SInt32 *error = (SInt32*)data;
        NSLog(@"Connection error : %d", *error);
        StreamErrorOccured(clientTCP);
    }
}
- (void) ConnectionSuccess
{
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSocketGetNative(socket), &readStream, &writeStream);
    CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue);
    CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue);
    CFStreamClientContext dataStreamContext = {0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL};  
    CFOptionFlags events = kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable | kCFStreamEventOpenCompleted;
    if (CFReadStreamSetClient(readStream, events, readStreamEventCallBack , &dataStreamContext)) 
    {
        CFReadStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(readStream, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    }
    if (CFWriteStreamSetClient(writeStream, kCFStreamEventOpenCompleted | kCFStreamEventCanAcceptBytes | kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred | kCFStreamEventEndEncountered,
                               writeStreamEventCallBack, &dataStreamContext))
    {
        CFWriteStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(writeStream, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    }else {
        NSLog(@"can't create write stream client");
    }

    CFReadStreamOpen(readStream);
    CFWriteStreamOpen(writeStream);

    NSLog(@"Connection Success");
}
```

Note that I registered a callback on the kCFStreamEventCanAcceptBytes event and kCFStreamEventOpenCompleted events. In this callback, I can see that the kCFStreamEventOpenCompleted occurred, but the kCFStreamEventCanAcceptBytes never occur !

When I try to write on my stream, I check the availability of the stream thanks to : CFWriteStreamCanAcceptBytes(writeStream). This function always return false.

If I try to write on the stream without calling CFWriteStreamCanAcceptBytes, the write operation loop forever.
My questions are : 
 1. Why don't I receive any  kCFStreamEventCanAcceptBytes event ?
 2.  Why can't I write on my stream ?

I saw that my problem is exactly the same that : [SIMILAR QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441822/unable-to-write-on-cfwritestreamwrite) but nobody reply to him.

Maybe I will be more lucky !

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer, but I met this problem as well.
A solution is to receive event 'kCFStreamEventCanAcceptBytes' in your writeStreamEventCallBack, and write data on this call back function. 
Actually the problem is, if you haven't send any data on the 'kCFStreamEventCanAcceptBytes' event, you can't send data next time.

[A page](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStreamConstants/index.html) of Apple dev documentation says:

When you use the CFStream API for networking, read and write operations on sockets can block. To prevent blocking:

1. Call CFReadStreamSetClient and CFWriteStreamSetClient to register to receive stream-related event notifications.
2. Call CFReadStreamScheduleWithRunLoop and CFWriteStreamScheduleWithRunLoop to schedule the stream on a run loop for receiving stream-related event notifications.
3. Call CFReadStreamOpen and CFWriteStreamOpen to open each stream.
4. Read only after receiving a kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable notification. Write only after receiving a kCFStreamEventCanAcceptBytes notification.